# How to install Magento using command-line

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-community

How to install Magento using command-line? I would like to know how to do this. I have tried to install Magento using command-line but I couldn't do it successfully. So I would like to know if it's possible to install Magento, using command-line, in my local PC?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible, There are lots of guidelines based on this topic.

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-magento-on-a-vps-running-ubuntu-12-04
- http://www.pixlpitch.com/install-magento-extensions-from-command-line/
- http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/run-magento-installer-from-command-line.html
- http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/installing-magento-via-ssh/
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/installing_magento_via_shell_ssh

Answer (score 0):

```
 php bin/magento setup:install --backend-frontname="admin" --key="admin" --session-save="files" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento_2_db" --db-user="root" --db-password="root" --base-url="http://local.magento.com/" --base-url-secure="https://local.magento2.com/" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --admin-email="pramod.kharade@example.com" --admin-firstname="Pramod" --admin-lastname="Kharade"
```