# Magento 2.2.2 Web Setup Wizard not visible in backend

Tags: magento2, admin, setup

Magento 2.2.2 Web Setup Wizard not visible in backend on Nginx and php7

Comment: You can install by command line:https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21319/how-to-install-magento-using-command-line/198506#198506

Comment: It is not fresh installation i've the site up and running I need to install magento upgrade and some extensions, but no web setup wizard

Comment: Do one thing, remove var,pub/static, generated folder and try to run upgrade command

Comment: Even though , it won't  work then check nginx log or Magento exception log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is a known issue.
since early 2.0 and still not fixed in 2.3.1

https://github.com/magento/magento2/projects/14#card-3854114

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Setup/MenuBuilder.php#L47

```
  /**
     * Removes 'Web Setup Wizard' from the menu if doc root is pub and no setup url variable is specified.
     *
     * @param Builder $subject
     * @param Menu $menu
     * @return Menu
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    public function afterGetResult(Builder $subject, Menu $menu)
    {
        if ($this->docRootLocator->isPub()) {
            $menu->remove('Magento_Backend::setup_wizard');
        }
        return $menu;
    }
}
```

==============================================================================
**FIX:**

you can:

1. comment that function.
2. create nginx rewrite logic.
3. using manual redirect:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4159#issuecomment-244483087

dont forget that you must have 2 doc roots for your website and setup.

```
## Set Magento root folder
set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html;
## Set main public directory /pub
root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;
```

...

```
location ~ ^/(setup|update) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
```

Comment: till then what is the work around?

Comment: see update answer

Comment: I'm having an issue using apache, php7, Magento CE 2.2.6 and /setup/ (outside of /pub/). The Menu item is present in the admin menu but when clicked it redirects to 404 Not Found Whoops...
Any instruction on how to debug or solve this?

Answer (score 0):

if you get 500 error after access 'yoursite/setup' please add following code after first php tag

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '2000M');`

It will show you error. In my case I use redis to store cache, it causes the issue, I have to change session to file:

`'session' => [
    'save' => 'files'
  ],`

In my case, I comment this line of code:

`$menu->remove('Magento_Backend::setup_wizard');`

In file: vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Setup/MenuBuilder.php
Then get 500 error. I resolved 500 error as the way above.